# Is there a way to localize android app without using values/strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, string, localization, translation

My android application supports 3 languages(english, korean, russian) and I'm planning to support more of it.
because of app characteristics, it has millions of line(translation) in each strings.xml file. so the size of the all string.xml files exceeds 1MB.

I think it's too large.

Is there a way to localize android app without using values/strings.xml?
or...trim the size of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this would be to put the *data* strings in an SQLite database instead of putting them all in `strings-xx` resource files. I once worked on a project with tons of strings in different languages. The solution we came up with was to put *only* the UI-related strings in the `strings-xx` resource files, and the data strings in SQLite tables. This reduced the APK size significantly.

By UI-related strings I mean those like screen titles, button/widget texts, constant strings with format parameters and so on. Data strings would be those that are dependent on or received in an API response.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom resource loading using a more space efficient file format than xml, but I doubt its worth the effort.

If you want to do this, check for the current locale to decide which resources to load:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```